# load data infile is not allowed MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mariadb, bulkinsert

I created a PHP script that imports posts from a CSV file into a WordPress website.

To do this, I first bulk import the posts into a table of the WP website database and then the PHP script creates the posts.
The bulk insert MYSQL query I use is the following:

```
load data local infile '/var/www/vhosts/sitenamehere.test/test.csv' into table test_table character set latin1 fields terminated by ';' lines terminated by '\r\n' ignore 1 lines;
```

When I run the script from the server I get the following error:

> > "the used command is not allowed with this MariaDB version for the query load data local infile..."

The problem occurs only when I execute the script from the server, in fact if I run the same query from phpMyAdmin, it lets me import the file.

Since my scripts not only imports but also updates posts, the intention was to create a cron job so that the script is executed multiple times a day. Obviously this is not possible if I keep getting the same error.

I tried adding:

- the line `local-infile=1` under the section `[client]` and `[mysqld]` of `my.cnf`
- the line `mysql.allow_local_infile=On` under the `[mysql]` section of
  `my.cnf`
- the line `mysql.allow_local_infile=On` under the `[MySQLi]` section of `php.ini` located at `/opt/plesk/php/7.1/etc`

But nothing helped. Any ideas?

Comment: Create a bash file that execute the command instead of a php file...use the bash file in your cron...profit!

Comment: Thanks @Hackerman that worked

Comment: Glad to help @Marco

Answer (score 1):

You must add `AllowLoadLocalInfile=true;` to your MySQL/MariaDB server connection string when you want to load a local file.

If using something like a LOAD LOCAL INFILE command then add `--local_infile=1` to the command itself and it should work.

In recent versions of both servers this functionality is disabled by default and should only be enabled when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The guide at 
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/load-data-infile/
says

> If the local_infile system variable is set to 0, attempts to perform a LOAD DATA LOCAL will fail with an error message.

You best bet is to change the my.ini file that's being used.

Moreover the used database user needs the FILE privilege.