# Mariadb error: the used command is not allowed with this MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

In mariadb, when I use "load data local infile" into a php script, I get this error message:

> the used command is not allowed with this MariaDB version for the query load data local infile

This is the same thing than on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47940175/load-data-infile-is-not-allowed-mariadb/52993318#52993318).

I'm on CentOS 7 - Plesk Onyx and my `my.cnf` contains:

```
local-infile=1
```

If I use "load data infile", I can import my csv file into my MySQL table but the csv file must to be located into the directory `/var/lib/mysql/my_database/`

But I can't create a csv file into `/var/lib/mysql/my_database/` from a php script located into `/var/www/vhosts/my-website.com/httpdocs/my_script.php`

if I use "load data infile", I can import my csv file into my MySQL table but the csv file must to be located into the directory /var/lib/mysql/my_database/

But I can't create a csv file into /var/lib/mysql/my_database/ from a php script located into /var/www/vhosts/my-website.com/httpdocs/my_script.php it doesn't work!

What is the solution?

Comment: Your php does not have permission to access these folders.

Answer (score 0):

See PHP's open_basedir for restrictions on PHP writing: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Comment: What would be the value of open_basedir to add into my php.ini file?

1) I add only the directory of my mysql database: /var/lib/mysql/my_database/

2) I add all directories, such as (MySQL database and all the directories of the files of my websites): /var/lib/mysql/my_database/, /var/www/vhosts/my-website.com/httpdocs/, /var/www/vhosts/my-other-website.com/httpdocs/

Comment: I think only the one directory needs to be added.  Be aware that this opens a security risk.